# Why is the set of positive definite matrices in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ a positive cone

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

The set of positive definite matrices in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is geometrically a positive cone. This statement appears in almost every article on real positive definite matrices I read but without a proof. **Where can I find a general proof, please? In addition, if I assume this statement is true, does it imply that the set of positive definite matrices is a manifold or a sub-manifold of $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$?**

Comment: What part of the definition are you having trouble verifying?

Comment: I know what positive definite matrices are. And I know what a cone is, at least in $\mathbb R^3$? But I don't know why the two are equivalent which seems true from the statement I quoted.

Comment: What definition of a cone are you working with?

Comment: In fact, I want to show that the set of all inner products in $\mathbb R^3$ is some manifold and determine its dimension. I learnt that these inner products are equivalent to the set of positive definite matrices. After that I read the statement I quoted. So I do not know the definition of cone used in this statement.

Comment: I believe the definition in question may be that of a [convex cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) - and I think it's pretty intuitive that the set of positive definite matrices satisfies it (positive definite matrices correspond to positive quadratic forms, and positive linear combination of those is obviously positive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's immediate from the definitions. An $n\times n$  real matrix $A$ is positive definite if (1) it is symmetric ($A^t=A$) and (2) $v^tAv>0$ for all non-zero column vectors $v\in\mathbb R^n$. The 1st condition is linear, so defines a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^{n^2},$ of dimension $n(n+1)/2$ (easy exercise). The 2nd condition defines an  open subset of $\mathbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$ which is a convex cone; ie a subset  closed under linear combinations with positive coefficients. This is very easy to verify. To show that its open you use the fact that $(v,A)\mapsto v^tAv$ is a continuous function. Thus your set is an $n(n+1)/2$ dimensional manifold, a convex open subset of $\mathbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$.